# Как добавить изображение в комментарий?

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

У контакте есть стандартный виджет - добавление комментариев на сайт. При добавлении комментария, он отображается на стене пользователя, который его оставил.
Можно ли сделать, чтобы к нему крепилась определенная картинка со страницы сайта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя. [Документация виджета](https://vk.com/developers.php?o=-1&p=%C4%EE%EA%F3%EC%E5%ED%F2%E0%F6%E8%FF+%EE+%E2%E8%E4%E6%E5%F2%E5+%EA%EE%EC%EC%E5%ED%F2%E0%F0%E8%E5%E2) описывает свойства и события виджета, и не похоже, чтобы между отправкой коммента и его публикацией, ваш сайт мог вмешаться.

Можно просто средствами VK API постить на стену юзера: например, он вводит текст, к нему прилепляетс картинка-аттачмент, возникает popup где спрашивается подтверждение, действительно ли вы согласны разместить у себя на стене пост такого содержания (показывает превью, в т.ч. картинку), и если "Ок" - пост появится на стене. Но это не будет комментарий, как через виджет.